# On the purpose of human existence and unequal ability to understand complex things

Tags: existence, intelligence

I'm one of those people who think that the most important concern for us is to precisely understand the purpose of human existence ... I'm really surprised that our governments around the earth, even the most powerful, don't really invest a lot of money to solve this issue together ...

It seems that it is a very complex task anyway and even among the most brilliant people of our societies ( Western, Asian, African, etc ... ) there is opposition. But wait a second, can you imagine that if a guy like Einstein, Terrence Tao, Stephen Hawking or Albert Camus is unable to precisely answer to that without ambiguity, what about the rest of normal people which are considered less intelligent, unable to construct some abstractions, even don't know too much things about metaphysics, logics, religions, history, advanced physics ...

If human people are really unequal on the basis of intelligence even considering his multiple forms, this question for more justice and equality should get an evident answer without ambiguity... Is it the case ? I'm not sure ...

What do you think about that ? Sometimes i'm just tempted to  conclude that the world is just fundamentally unfair ...

Comment: Why do you assume that human existence has some purpose beyond whatever you declare for yourself?

Comment: whatever i declare for myself ? are you talking about unequality  i mentionned ?